# SASS stripping out -moz-box-sizing

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I am using gulp to run a build command which compiles my SASS files.  When I compile these SASS files locally, they are fine, but when I compile them on my server, SASS strips out all -moz-box-sizing styles.  Are there any settings in SASS what would do that?

Any recommendations on where to start would be helpful.

Also, I forgot to mention the box-sizing properties are being applied using a mixin.  The mixin simply adds all the vendor prefixes.

Comment: Are the other box-sizing properties appearing?

Comment: Also, are your local version and server version of SASS the same?

Comment: yes, the other box-sizing properties are appearing.  I have not checked the SASS versions, would that cause this?

Comment: Sass does not strip out properties.  Period.  Unless nulls are involved.

Comment: After a lot more testing I found that it might not be SASS, it might be Gulp... or something else in my build process.  I'm going to keep trying to reproduce.